# order number as file name wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, woocommerce, filenames

I'm using *wordpress* with *woocommerce* and I've installed a *plugin* for file uploads, which put into checkout page, when the order was placed. I need this uploader to change the name of uploaded file to the order number current placed. see the picture...

**Order Number as file name by upload**

[image]

This put in *woocommerce* order number in the front-end site

`<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>`

In **functions.php** I have this code as test to handle with file name by uploading:

```
add_filter('wfu_before_file_upload', 'wfu_before_file_upload_handler', 10, 2);

function wfu_before_file_upload_handler($file_path, $file_unique_id) { 
        // separate file name from file path
        $only_filename = basename($file_path);
        $only_filepath = substr($file_path, 0, - strlen($only_filename));
        // separate file extension from file name
        $dot_pos = strrpos($only_filename, ".");
        if ( $dot_pos ) {
                $ext_part = substr($only_filename, $dot_pos);
                $name_part = substr($only_filename, 0, $dot_pos);
        }
        // add timestamp to the end of name_part
        $current_datetime = gmdate("U");
        $only_filename = $name_part . "-" . gmdate("YmdHis", $current_datetime) . $ext_part;
        // return the full file path
        $file_path = $only_filepath . $only_filename;
        return $file_path;
}
```

This is actually from the *plugin* developer as example, how to handle file name of uploaded file with *wordpress* filter.

I would like to make `$current_order_number` instead of `$current_datetime` but how I can then get the current order number from database? I've tried following:

```
$order = get_order_number();
$current_order_number = $order;
$new_filename = $current_order_number . $ext_part;
// return the full file path
$file_path = $only_filepath . $new_filename;
return $file_path;
```

But it's not working. I still get error message by uploading the file. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Tomas

Comment: Pretty sure you can't change the filename after it has been uploaded. Well but easily anyway. There is a plugin. Is the upload happening before the order is complete? In that case an order number would nut be available. If you were uploading and adding a media attachment then I think you could change the attachment title.

Comment: I want to change it before upload. The upload possibility shows up, when the order is already placed, that means, that I see the order number and also the order number is already in database. Then comes the upload form and to be able to identity, to which order the current file belongs, I need to change the name by uploading for the order number. Its not as attachment of some form, it is an upload field available after placing the order.